# Can I change the first screen of tab item programatically?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Can I change the first screen of a tab item programatically?

For example,

> When user is in Tab A, upon tapping a button there, user will be
>   navigated to Tab C with Screen 1 However, when user is in Tab C, upon
>   tapping a button here, user will be navigated to Tab C with Screen 2.
>   Therefore, both screen 1 and 2 will be the first screen of Tab C
>   depend on where the user comes from.

Can I achieve something like that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this post [How to replace a navigation root controller by tab bar controller in existing iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190040/how-to-replace-a-navigation-root-controller-by-tab-bar-controller-in-existing-ip) , can change the view controllers by this code:

```
NSMutableArray * viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


FirstViewController * firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController * nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
[firstViewController release];
[viewControllers addObject:nvc];
[nvc release];

SecondViewController * secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
[secondViewController release];
[viewControllers addObject:nvc];
[nvc release];

UITabBarController * tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```